# C# escape characters to delphi

Tags: delphi, websocket

I'm trying to convert some application in .net to delphi

but i my tool doesn't work  , so i dont if this is the right way or no

this is the code from c#

```
websocket.Send("hello server\n\x00");
websocket.Send("1 guest\n\x00");
websocket.Send("0 0 -\n\x00");
```

this is delphi code (my try)

```
  WSClient1.SendText('hello server'+ #13 + #10 + #0);
  WSClient1.SendText('1 guest'+ #13 + #10 + #0);
  WSClient1.Sendtext('0 0 -' + #13 + #10 + #0);
```

but i don't get the response i want .. in c# it gives back the result with "fileno" string but in my tool i never see it just another string (strings are just info about the server)

Comment: FWIW, there is no need for the `+`. `'hello server'#13#10#0` is one valid string literal. You can even do `'hello'#10#13'server'#13#10'how are you?'#0` .

Comment: What type is WSClient1? [edit] your question

Comment: Maybe WSClient1 doesn't transmit the nulls over the wire, but your server side code requires it to? Instead of SendText, see if there's a SendBytes( ) method, or write one. 

I also wonder whether websocket (in C#) is transmitting Unicode (UTF16) or ANSI data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\n` escape sequence represents "New line".  It is represented in the un-escaped string as a single #10 character (ASCII code 10), **not** a CR/LF pair.

Secondly, the `\x00` terminating sequence on the strings in the C# code is most likely required by the **Send()** API due to the fact that strings in C# are not intrinsically null terminated.  if this is the case then you do not need to include this null in the Delphi code at all.  In Delphi strings are already null terminated.

So all you need to do is (for example):

```
WSClient1.Send('hello fcserver'+ #10);
```

I should add that without precise details of the **WSClient1** object and the **Send()** method involved, the latter observation w.r.t terminating null characters may prove to be incorrect but I am fairly confident it is accurate.

Comment: It is not uncommon for network protocols to send null terminated strings over the wire, in cases were strings are not transmitted with preceding lengths. The `\x00` is explicitly including a null terminator in the transmitted data, as presumably `Send(string)` takes the string's length into account and ignores any implicit null on the end.  The same would be true in Delphi, if `Send()` just sends the raw String data with respect to its `Length()`, so an explicit null would be needed as well: `WSClient1.Send('hello fcserver'+ #10 + #0);`

Comment: @Remy: that's one possibility as I allude to in the closing para of the answer (I didn't wish to labour the details in case it was an irrelevant distraction).  However, unlike Delphi, there is no implicit NULL on a C# string.  Without the explicit NULL there is no NULL and w.r.t the *protocol* a terminal NULL appears to be redundant given the use of the new line terminator.  The question is whether the *parameter on the Send method itself* requires NULL termination.  But without the details of the Send method involved it's not possible to say for sure.